# Integrating Twitter Feed in Rails 4 App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, twitter-gem

I'm trying to integrate twitter feed into my rails four 4 app, a cms for that matter. I settled of twitter gem and had it successfully installed.
I set up the following in application_controller.rb.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

protect_from_forgery with: :exception

require 'twitter'

  @client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
    config.consumer_key = 'my consumer key'
    config.consumer_secret = 'my consumer secret'
    config.access_token = 'access token'
    config.access_token_secret = 'access token secret'
  end
end
```

Note: I've omitted my credentials here but have them correctly in my app.
Then I added the following in my views i.e application.html.erb

```
<section id="tweets">
  <ul>
    <% @client.each do |tweet| %>
      <li><%=  tweet.text %></li>
    <% end %>  
  </ul>
</section>
```

I get the following error

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

What could I be doing wrong? I've read through the twitter gem documentation, started off by setting up an initializer, realized my local variable in the initializer lost scope by the time I was in the views so I deleted it and added the initialization in the controller. Note it's `@client` A detailed answer would be appreciated.

Comment: Has my answer been helpfu?

Comment: @majioa not really. Actaually I decided to use twitter widget from my twitter account. it solved the issue for me.

Comment: Who is it? if you got the answer yourself, write it below %)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up using twitter widget form my twitter account. Here's the code that solved my problem

```
<div class="span4">
  <a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/YourHandle" data-widget-id="MyTwitterId">Tweets by YourHandle</a>
  <script>
    !function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';
    if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"
    ;fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
  </script>
</div>
```

NOTE: Replace YourHandle with your twitter handle. I've also omitted my data widget id. To get yours go to your twitter settings then create twitter widget. A similar code will be generated which you can embed on your site.